# How to quantify the reflectance in an image?

Tags: computer-vision

I am working on a problem where I have to train a CNN to recognize different kinds of surfaces. One important characteristic of the surfaces I am interested is is how reflective they are. I have been trying to find a method that quantifies how "shiny" a surface is, but I have not found much. I am hoping that someone can point me toward a method or some research into this kind of problem.

Comment: cnn is all about supervised learning...define a score for each image and train accordingly

Comment: It would be difficult to determine how shiny a surface is _in absolute terms_ without a reference value of some sort, but you could probably estimate the _relative_ reflectance by comparing the apparent luminance of surfaces with the background luminance (I would expect shinier surfaces to appear brighter). However, this depends on a lot of factors, mainly orientation (if a surface is facing away from a light source, it would appear darker) and internal illumination (what is the reflectance of a light bulb when it is turned on?).

Answer (score 1):

You should first know about the layer-wise working of a convolutional neural network. Read this https://distill.pub/2018/building-blocks/

Each layer of a cnn forms representations that are increasingly complex , which are  combinations of simpler representations formed by its previous layers. 
"shine" is not a pattern (from image processing perspective). shine occurs due to change in intensity values.

And for quantifying "shine" you dont have to go for convolutional networks only , there are many more simpler methods for such tasks you could try fitting simple linear model and progress towards more complex ones.

and for classifying textures , there is interesting work going with "invariant scattering convolutional networks" you should check that.